# ssh picking wrong private key even after config file change

Tags: rsa, ssh-keys, dbeaver, ssh-tunnel, ed25519

I am trying to connect to a database through ssh tunnel in Dbeaver.
However, even after explicitly specifying private key, the ssh still looks for the wrong key (or is it wrongly encoded key) while connecting.

I have updated the config file to use the intended private key.
But it somehow does not use it, or it is using a different encryption on that key.

```
(base) arpit@ASFD876876 .ssh % pwd
/Users/arpit/.ssh
(base) arpit@ASFD876876 .ssh % ls -ltr
total 24
-rw-------  1 arpit  test  2622 Jan 17 15:20 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 arpit  test   586 Jan 17 15:20 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 arpit  test   135 Jan 22 13:37 config
(base) arpit@ASFD876876 .ssh % cat config 
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host jump
  HostName jump.services
  User arpit
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
(base) arpit@ASFD876876 .ssh %
```

As shown below, I have given the path to rsa private key but, the test connection looks for ssh-ed25519 encrypted key.

[image]

I am not sure what am I missing. Kindly guide me through. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ssh-ed25519` is not a file name, but key type and it's not your key but the key of the remote machine
To manually list keys of the remote host you can use

```bash
ssh-keyscan -H jump.services
```

Comment: My public key starts with ssh-rsa

`(base) arpit@ASFD876876 .ssh % cat id_rsa.pub 

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAB.....`

Comment: Eh my fault it it's not your but fingerprint of the remote host that you are trying to connect, and it's asking `do you trust it?` based on fingerprint, you can manually trust it by using `ssh-keyscan -H jump.services >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: I would like to say that I am pretty sure i added it last time to known_host file but it didn't work. So I deleted the known_hosts file and was trying to understand ed25519 thing. 
I don't know what changed. I tried regenerating rsa keys and added it to known host again and this time it worked.

Clearly something was not right last time. Anyway thanks for the advice